# Validate text boxes using Jquery Validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using

```
[Jquery validation plugin][1] 


  [1]: https://jqueryvalidation.org,
```

How can i validate if at least one of three options was filled ?

Creating a method via .addMethod ? i am trying to adapt from this fiddle but i have text boxes instead of select boxes:

```
 [validate select box][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/8x1yj0pr/
```

I did not get any message, here is what i try until now:

```
$.validator.addMethod("validateOptions", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional( element ) ||
        ($('#firstname').val() != '' ||
        $('#username').val() != '' ||
            $('#email').val() != '' ||);
}, "Please provide at least one ");

$(document).ready(function() {
        var validator = $("#VerifyForm").validate({
            rules: {
                formFields: {
                   validateOptions: true,
                }
                firstname : {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                lastname : {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 7
                },
                email : {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
            },
```

Comment: Can you post your html code and full javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use a plugin just for that. Try this:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/4kq3r4ys/)</kbd>

```js
$('#submit').click(function(evt){ //<===============================
  var fn = $('#fn').val();
  var un = $('#un').val();
  var em = $('#em').val();
  if (fn !='' || un!='' || em!=''){
    alert('good to go');
  }else{
    evt.preventDefault(); //<===============================
    $('#fn').focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="fn" /><br>
<input type="text" id="un" /><br>
<input type="text" id="em" /><br>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: This work´s right, but how can i prevent the form from being submitted ? as i am using CakePHP 2.5

Comment: @ÂngeloRigo See modification to my answer. `event.preventDefault()` should do the trick.

Comment: Great ! Thank you! is working for me ! preventDefault stops the propagation, that is it ?.

Comment: No, it suppresses the default action of the `<form>`, which is to submit to either: (1) the page specified in the `action=xxxxx.php` tag attribute, or, if that is missing, (2) to the same page the form tag is on *(which causes a page refresh)*

Comment: How can i call inside the if the LeanModal jquery modal opensource project ? https://github.com/FinelySliced/leanModal.js i have tried using a closure :  if(1==1){
  
  $(function(){
    $('#content').leanModal({ top: 210, overlay: 0.45, closeButton: ".hidemodal" });
  });
 }

Comment: Angelo, I am busy right now with something else. If you ask this as a separate question (reference this post in your question), you will get your question read instantly by dozens of people who will try to help. That will be much faster than waiting for me. *Best wishes for your project.*

Comment: Tahnk you i do post at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37946064/how-can-i-call-a-jquery-modal-function-inside-an-conditional-if

Comment: No, just at stackoverflow.com - like you posted this one.  *Then include the URL to this post in your new question.*